# How to replace some data with empty value using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some data as below

```
var data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovVHlwZSAv"
```

I need only the data after base64,

```
JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovVHlwZSAv
```

I need only above data.How can we get this using reqex?

Can someone help
Thanks

Comment: split on comma or remove text until comma....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can target everything before base64 and a comma after it so you can use /.*base64,/. then use `replace()` to replace it with ""

```js
var data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQovVHlwZSAv"

console.log(data.replace(/.*base64,/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

So use split

```
data.split(',').pop()
```

or replace that matches everything up to the comma

```
data.replace(/[^,]+,/,'')
```